# How to display a list of all names of templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

In the client, I know you can use Template.[template name] to reference a specific template.

How could you get a list of all custom meteor templates included in your app that have been created by you (not meteor or included from a package)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what Richard said, you can check if the property on the Template object is a template like this:

```
var templates = [];
for(var key in Template){
  if(Blaze.isTemplate(Template[key])){
    templates.push( key );       
  }
}
console.log( templates );
```

You'd probably have to use a specific naming convention for identifying your own templates.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `Object.keys(Template)`. I attached a screenshot from the console.

[image]

Basically meteor creates a class called `Template`. We can iterate over all the keys in the template class.